# Android pay register android test app for stripe

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I have integrated stripe as the method define at stripe.com but when I press button. app show same dialog every time with this message:

> To make purchases using Android Pay, please set your cards in the android pay app.

I can't understand what the problem is. How can I set cards on android pay?

[image: Screenshot of my app]

Answer (score 0):

I am mentioning following steps these may be useful for you.

Step 1:- DownLoad Android Pay App from PlayStore. If you are not in us and you want to use android pay then you should have a us registered email id (You can make us email id with help of gmail ) then you can download android pay .

Step2: You can register you credit card in android pay now a days few credit cards are supported by android pay you can try with Visa, Master Card, American Express cards and other cards which support the android pay.

Step 3: Implement following points https://developers.google.com/android-pay/diagrams .

Note: Now android launched android pay in UK too.

If you have some problem then comment me.